# mongo group with $push not allowing duplicate key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following document structure :

```
{
readings:[
{"timestamp":"1234","data":"9"},
{"timestamp":"1234","data":"90"},
{"timestamp":"12" "data":"100"}]
}
```

Is it possible to group three array with duplicate keys.

**Expected result :**

```
{
"readings":["1234","1234","12"]
}
```

**my query :**

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "null",
      readings: {
        $push: "$readings.timestamp"
      }
    }
  }
];
```

but it's not allowing duplicate key.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue here, Check this :: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/xGaSzP3Edq4), Also what is this field `macid` ?

Comment: that's not working in mongo 4.2. macid is typo error

Comment: im using mongo 4.2 and c# driver 2.6.1

Comment: What is the error that you're getting ? Since you've changed  to ` _id: "null"` then it would iterate over all your docs, So your expected result will also change accordingly, result will have `_id:null`..

Comment: no error.this query not allowing duplicate entry
that means [
        "1234",
        "12"
      ] geting only one "1234" value.i want both value

Comment: `$push` should allow dups, did you try to execute query in given playground or directly on ur DB ?

Comment: it's not working in my db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readings` is an array, when you are grouping, you get array of arrays. If you flatten `readings` field and group it, you will get desired result.

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$readings"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "null",
      readings: {
        $push: "$readings.timestamp"
      }
    }
  }
])
```